# how to enable camara in webview for streaming?

Tags: android, android-webview

**i have developed streaming http application using html5 and jQuery. i can stream through the 
PC no problem.**

**now i need to enable camera and mic of android device in webview for streaming.
means the camera and audio should pass from the http protocol.**

**how would enable camera and audio ?**

**i am new for android please please help me.**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearHistory();
        //webView.loadUrl("http://122.181.157.2/educafewebsite/index.html");
        webView.loadUrl("http://122.181.157.9/chat2/index.html?Viresh");
    }
```